# How can I build OSGi bundles with SBT 0.10+?

Tags: scala, osgi, sbt

For SBT 0.7 there is https://github.com/weiglewilczek/bnd4sbt, but what to do for SBT 0.10 or 0.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a plugin from Typesafe: https://github.com/typesafehub/sbtosgi

Answer (score 2):

There is a [sketch of a plugin for SBT 0.11](https://gist.github.com/1289361) and an [open issue](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/bnd4sbt/issues/28) on the project you cited requesting support.